# Getting a popup menu to work on my site

Tags: mailchimp

I am trying to get a mailchimp from to popup once a button is clicked. The script is copied straight from their site, but could you tell me what I am doing wrong?
The button shows but nothing hapens when clicked - no console error:

```
<button id="btn_mailchimp">Subscribe</button>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>

    <script>
    function showMailchimpPopup() {
        require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) {   L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us12.list-  manage.com","uuid":"d48920bdaa7e3140a6b82da43","lid":"8b19baf440"}) })
    };
    document.getElementById("btn_mailchimp").onclick = function()     {showMailchimpPopup()};
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mailchimp script adds a session cookie called "**MCEvilPopupClosed**" while closing the popup.

If that cookie is set, then you can not open the popup again.
So we need to delete the cookie we click the button next time.
so please update your `showMailchimpPopup` function with the below code

```
function showMailchimpPopup() {
        document.cookie = 'MCEvilPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;'; 
        require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) {   L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us12.list-  manage.com","uuid":"d48920bdaa7e3140a6b82da43","lid":"8b19baf440"}) })
    };
```